# Compare value to previous row in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following for loop:

```
dataframe <- for (i in 2:nrow(dataframe) {
  if (dataframe$ColA[i] == dataframe$ColA[i-1]) {
    dataframe$ColB[i] <- "No"
  } else {
    dataframe$ColB[i] <- "Yes"
    }
}
dataframe$ColB[1] <- "Y"
```

`ColA` contains a string, and `ColB` contains either `Yes` or `No`. I'm attempting to compare column A's value to column A's value in the previous row. If `colA[2] == colA[1]`, then `colB[2]` should equal `"Yes"`, otherwise `colB` should equal `No`.

When I run the loop, it results in the data frame being `NULL (empty)`.

When I test individual instances, the comparison works as intended:

```
if (dataframe$ColA[2] == dataframe$ColA[2-1]) {
    dataframe$ColB[2] <- "No"
  } else {
    dataframe$ColB[2] <- "Yes"
    }
```

Any idea on how to fix the loop so it works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lag` to compare the values instead of a loop

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>%
      mutate(ColB = case_when(ColA == lag(ColA) ~ "No",
                 TRUE ~ "Yes"))
```

#### data

```
dataframe <- data.frame(ColA = c(1, 2, 3, 1,  1, 3))
```

Comment: Using lag is a good idea, however this answer is not working correctly. Out of ~38,000 records, only 4 are showing up as "No". The true amount should be roughly 19,000.

Comment: Here is an example after using your suggestion. `ColA[2] = "01be0ad4af7aeb1f6d2cc2b6b6d6d811"` and `ColA[3] = "01be0ad4af7aeb1f6d2cc2b6b6d6d811"`. However, `ColB[3] = "Yes"`. As you can see, they are exactly the same.

Comment: @newToCoding13  If you check my example, the 4th row is "Yes" and the next is "No" when both values are 1

Comment: @newToCoding13   You can check the output by changing my example to `dataframe$ColA[2:3] <- c("01be0ad4af7aeb1f6d2cc2b6b6d6d811", "01be0ad4af7aeb1f6d2cc2b6b6d6d811")`  It gives `ColB[3]` as `"No'`

Comment: it appears my data was not formatted as a data frame. Once I reformatted it, your example worked correctly. Thank you for the help!